# ¿Como reproducir un video en un lienzo canvas usando createJS?

Tags: javascript, createjs

Estoy haciendo un juego al que como fondo le coloco un archivo mp4, pero me gustaria hacerlo dentro del canvas usando la apis createJS, he buscado en la documentacion pero no consigo como hacerlo(No se si no busque lo suficiente).

```JavaScript
var SCREEN_WIDTH=window.screen.availWidth,
SCREEN_HEIGHT=window.screen.availHeight;
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas-game");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
if (!ctx) console.error("Alerta: Tu navegador es muy obsoleto para este juego. Recomiendo actualizar");
var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
var video=document.querySelector("#video-fondo");
video.autoplay=true;
video.loop=true;
video.width=SCREEN_WIDTH;
video.height=SCREEN_HEIGHT;
let vb= new createjs.VideoBuffer(video);
stage.addChild(new createjs.Bitmap(vb));
stage.update();
```

El problema es que no me reproduce, parece como si solo fuera una imagen.

Comment: Hola Daniel, he visitado la página de **createJS** y me parece que no reproduce video, es más como un canvas vitaminizado, con agregado de audio.

Comment: @MarcePuente Hola, he estado buscando y todo me sale es usar la clase Bitmap, ahora lo que pienso hacer es dibujarlo directo en la pantalla

Comment: Tal vez esto te [sirva](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas).

Comment: @MarcePuente Gracias, lo intentaré de este modo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que solo dibujo un `frame` del video y no lo dibujas todos. Para solucionarlo hay que hacer una animacion donde se obtenga todos los `frames` que se desea mediante la funcion `setInterval` o usando la biblioteca tweenjs que viene con `easejs`:

```js
function init(){
  var SCREEN_WIDTH=window.screen.availWidth,
  SCREEN_HEIGHT=window.screen.availHeight;
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas-game");
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (!ctx) console.error("Alerta: Tu navegador es muy obsoleto para este juego. Recomiendo actualizar");
  var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  var video=document.querySelector("#video-fondo");
  video.autoplay=true;
  video.loop=true;
  video.muted=true;//Para que el navegador no se queje por la falta de iteracion.
  
  //video.width=SCREEN_WIDTH;//Aqui no sirve de nada:(
  //video.height=SCREEN_HEIGHT;// Hay que usar el metodo setTransform de Bitmap para redimensionar la imagen. No digo como porque no entiendo mucho de como funciona.
  video.play();//Importante. Iniciar el video.
  let vb= new createjs.VideoBuffer(video);
  let img=new createjs.Bitmap(vb);//videobuffer tiene un metodo llamado getImage que le le pasa la imagen actual del video.
  stage.addChild(img);
  stage.update();
  setInterval(function(){
    stage.removeChild(img);//Eliminamos la imagen.
    img=new createjs.Bitmap(vb.getImage());//Pasamos al siguiente cuadro
    //o si quieres: img=new createjs.Bitmap(vb);
    stage.addChild(img);
    stage.update();
  },60);
}
```

```css
canvas{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>Click en la imagen para iniciar el video.</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" onclick="init()" id="video-fondo"></video>
<canvas id="canvas-game"></canvas>
<p>Video sacado de <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">w3schools</a> del curso <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp">HTML</a> sobre la etiqueta video.
```

Comment: @MarcePuente Consegui la manera de hacerlo usando la biblioteca mensionada. Me di cuenta porque en el curso que pusiste se debia hacer lo mismo que aqui. Gracias